# C Programming- FindFirstFile returning Invalid_handle_value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, handle, filesize

I've looked all over the place for the past couple of hours trying to find an answer for this, but i have a function meant to get the file size of one of my command line arguments, but in doing so my handle has constantly been returning an invalid value. If there's anyone willing to help me out it would be much appreciated. My function code is as follows:

```
int getSmallFileLength(const char *fileName, WIN32_FIND_DATA data)
{
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(&fileName, &data);
int fileSize = data.nFileSizeLow;

if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\nyou got an error.");
    return -1;
}
else
{
    printf("\nyour file size is %s", fileSize);
}

return fileSize;
}
```

If the main code would help resolve this i will post it, but in the meanwhile I am cleaning up the mess that it is to make it readable. It is passing in my Win32_find_data variable and the file.

I am also using Visual Studio 2013.

and here was the main code now:

```
   #pragma warning (disable:4996)
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "cA5_proto.h"

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
     int x;
     int argNum = 1;
     int counter = 0;

printf("Command: %s\n", argv[0]);
for (argNum = 1; argNum < argc; argNum++)
{
    printf("arg #%d: %s\n", argNum, argv[argNum]);
}

if (argc != 2) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
{
    /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
    printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]);
}
else
{

    // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *fileOutput = fopen("contents.txt", "a");
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData = { 0 };
    getSmallFileLength(file,fileData);

    /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on fnailure */
    if (file == 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
    }
    else
    {


            /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
            indicates the end of the file.  Note that the idiom of "assign
            to a variable, check the value" used below works because
            the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */

        //getSmallFileLength(argv[1]);              //getSmallFileLength outputs either the file size or an error

        printf("\nThe contents are: \n");
        while ((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
                                                //IN A FOR LOOP FOR THE LENGTH OF THE FILE SIZE HELPS OUTPUT A \N EVERY 10 CHARACTERS

            if (counter > 0)
            {
                if (counter == 10 || counter % 10 == 0)  //SEPERATE LINES WITH A \N EVERY TEN
                {
                    fprintf(fileOutput, "\n");

                }
            }

            if (x>10 && x<100)                  //puts a zero in front of two digit numbers in the contents output file
            {
                fprintf(fileOutput, "0");
            }
            fprintf(fileOutput, "%d ",x);



            printf("%c", x);
            counter++;

        }
        printf("\n");

        //CLOSE FILES HERE
        fprintf(fileOutput, "\n");              //PUT A \N AT THE END OF THE FILE
        fclose(fileOutput);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

The only warning i get from vsb is the following:Warning
1   warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'const char *'

Comment: That's _all_ the code you're showing us? and isn't is `c++`?

Comment: `FindFirstFile(&fileName, &data)` --> `FindFirstFile(fileName, &data)`

Comment: The compiler should give you at least a warning for `HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(&fileName, &data);`

Comment: Sorry @SouravGhosh i was tidying it, i dont know why i didnt just wait to post it along with the question.

Comment: and i have no idea why that was even there @BLUEPIXY, but i took it out and i still receive an error

Comment: Not directly related to your problem: in `getSmallFileLength` you should do a `FindClose(handle)` if `FindFirstFile` succeeded. General advice: don't ignore warnings, actually warnings are often more like errors.

Comment: oh thank you very much @MichaelWalz. and sorry if my coding is terrible i'm just getting used to all of this

Comment: `getSmallFileLength(file,fileData);` -->  `getSmallFileLength(argv[1], fileData);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for the quick reply, i had my attempt at that except when i go to run it the program will stop working

Comment: use debugger of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

try small test code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    printf ("Target file is %s.\n", argv[1]);
    hFind = FindFirstFile(argv[1], &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf ("Invalid File Handle. Get Last Error reports %d\n", GetLastError ());
    } else {
        printf ("The first file found is %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        printf ("The first file size is %d\n", FindFileData.nFileSizeLow);
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That was able to find the file size so thank you, I'll see how i can go from there I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
per this link:
<http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx>
the returned value, when equal to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE means the file was not found.

in looking at your code, your passing the address of the address of the filename string 
(a meaningless value)
what should be passed is 'filename' not '&filename'
```

Comment: hey thank you for taking the time to answer, that just happened to be a typo from when i was frustrated, I'm sorry about that